# Unable to create convenience initializer for UIImagePickerController

Tags: swift

I'm trying to create a convenience initializer for `UIImagePickerController` but I'm running into the following error:

```
extension UIImagePickerController {
    convenience init(sourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceType, delegate: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate?) {
        self.init()
        self.sourceType = sourceType
        self.delegate = delegate
    }
}
```

**Error Message**

```
Cannot assign a value of type 'UIImagePickerControllerDelegate?' to a value of type 'protocol <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>?'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking around I came up with the following but this seems a little cumbersome.

```
extension UIImagePickerController {
    convenience init<T: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate where T: UINavigationControllerDelegate>(sourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceType, delegate: T?) {
        self.init()
        self.sourceType = sourceType
        self.delegate = delegate
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a little cumbersome, but do you see why you need to do that?